# Display the list of post meta depending on the array of post ID in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a post meta called car_code created in ACF and I need to display 
the value of car_code depending on the post ID inside $d. I am Stuck with this code:
$IDs = array("1101", "1102", "1103");
the $d should display 1101 for me to get the value of car_code.

```
    foreach ($IDs as $d) {
         $the_code = get_post_meta( $d, 'car_code' ); 
    }
```

I need a display like this: CODE1, CODE2, CODE3

Comment: Add to question the code with which you collect posts id into an array $IDs. What the $d variable displays?

Comment: Hi I have updated the question. I hope it is clear. The $the_code should display the value of post meta regardless of the $d.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it! I needed to add [0] to get the value from the get_post_meta().

```
        foreach ($IDs as $d) {
            $the_code = get_post_meta( $d, 'car_code' ); 
            $car_code .= '; '.$the_code[0]; //needed to added
        }
```